# OmniComplete and Vim issues

Tags: syntax-error, vim, omnicomplete

I'm trying to get omnicomplete to work for C++, and while everything seems to be in order, when I reset my omnifunc to be `omnifunc=omni#cpp#complete#Main`, the plugin does not recognize the omnifunc, and I get a `pattern not found` error. I've installed Ctags and put it in `.vim/<name_of_dir>`, along with adding `cpp_src` to `.vim/tags` and running the necessary commands. (see [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion) for more info)

The issue is that, no matter what I try, I still get this error. What can I do to get this working? I've tried this before, and the first time has just been a headache which resulted in me not being able to get it to work. This time, however, I'm determined.

**VimRc**

```
  1 syntax on
  2 set number
  3 set autoindent
  4 set ft=nasm
  5 set ts=4
  6 set nowrap
  7 set nocp
  8 filetype plugin on
  9 map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>
 10 
 11 autocmd FileType cpp set omnifunc=omni#cpp#complete#Main
 12 
 13 " configure tags - add additional tags here or comment out not-used ones
 14 set tags+=~/.vim/tags/cpp
 15 set tags+=~/.vim/tags/gl
 16 set tags+=~/.vim/tags/sdl
 17 " set tags+=~/.vim/tags/qt4
 18 " " build tags of your own project with Ctrl-F12
 19 map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>
 20 "
 21 " " OmniCppComplete
 22 let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1
 23 let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1
 24 let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1
 25 let OmniCpp_ShowPrototypeInAbbr = 1 " show function parameters
 26 let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1 " autocomplete after .
 27 let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1 " autocomplete after ->
 28 let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 " autocomplete after ::
 29 let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces = ["std", "_GLIBCXX_STD"]
 30 " " automatically open and close the popup menu / preview window
 31 au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif
 32 set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview
```

As always, any help is much appreciated.

**Update**

Posting my Ctags file for others to inspect in case there is an issue with that:

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields-+iaS --extra=+q .

map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, Vim can't find your tags file. Your command `ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields-+iaS --extra=+q .` will create `tags` file in current directory. Make sure that this is what you want.

Please execute the following command:

`:set tags?`

and make sure your tags file is present in resulting list. You can also place cursor at any symbol (say, some class name) and press `Ctrl-]`. Vim will jump to this symbol definition if your `tags` is OK. If it is not, then, of course, `omnicppcomplete` will not work. (I use `omnicppcomplete` for more than year, and it works. Not perfectly with complicated classes/structs, but works.)

And, finally, check [my answer here](http://goo.gl/Ybu2p), because i would recommend absolutelly the same: **to get perfect C/C++/Objective-C code completion you should use [Clang Complete](http://goo.gl/hu0tA)** (no `ctags` is needed for this kind of completion).

And if you want tags to be present (say, to easily jump to symbol definition), please use [Indexer](http://goo.gl/OPHk8) plugin.